# How to find records when input is large in mongo

Tags: mongodb

I have collection name `APT` like

```json
{"aid":1000,
"name": "aa",
"details": [{"Subject":"English","Marks":"85"},{"Subject":"Maths","Marks":"65"}]
}
```

I need to find all details against the `aid`. List of `aid` is in `excel` file and it is more than 5000 `aid` in `excel`.
How should I write query in `mongo` to get name and details for 5000 records in `mongo` shell?

Comment: I am getting confused with excel and mongo. What is the role of excel in this problem ?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow!!. Can you also show what solutions you have tried

Comment: if there is single aid request then i can write query like db.APT.find({"aid" :1000}) but i want to import all 5000 records detail.

Comment: APT collection contains more 1000000 records and out these records i need details for some aids which are in excel file. Like Aid 1002,20001,50001.....................

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking at a query using [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/).

e.g.

```
db.collection.find({ "aid": { $in: [1000, 1002, 1005, 10001] }});
```

##### Things to note.

The $in operator compares each parameter to each document in the collection, which can lead to performance issues.

To improve performance:

- It is recommended that you limit the number of parameters passed to the $in operator to tens of values.
- Using hundreds of parameters or more **can negatively impact query performance**.
- Create an index on the field you want to query. (e.g. aid)

Comment: How should i pass more than 5000 aid in "$in"? query is not accepting 5000 aid  in "$in".

Comment: Can you only find using those numbers? If cannot 5000, then do 500 batches of 10.